# Dataset of shell commands with corresponding sentences

Tags: data-request, nlp

I'm looking for datasets that contain a list of shell commands (any kind of [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_(computing)): bash, sh,  [Windows shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_shell), …) where each shell command is associated with at least one sentence written in English that explains what the shell command does. Examples:

- *what’s in this folder* -> `ls`
- *how much available disk space do I have left* -> `df -h`
- *install htop* -> `apt-get install -y htop`

Answer (score 2):

[`apropos`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/apropos.1.html) command will get you part of the way there.

`apropos find` spits out all commands named find or with find in the short description. You can start to hack away from there.